# JQuery toggle() - Element only displayed after JQuery submit function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, submit, toggle

I'm trying to display a loading gif at the beginning of a JQuery submit function, but the gif is only displayed after the submit function ends. (Each of the alerts are displayed before the gif)

For the ajax, I currently set it to always respond with an error saying "No video chosen".

JQuery

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#loading_gif").toggle();
    alert('The gif should be displayed');

    var Fdata = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/send_video",
        data: Fdata,
        processData:false,
        contentType: false,
        async:false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert('success');
            //commented or else the gif is never displayed
            //$("#loading_gif").toggle();
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert('error');
            e = document.getElementById("error");
            e.innerHTML =  JSON.parse(error.responseText);
            //commented or else the gif is never displayed
            //$("#loading_gif").toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="error"></div>
<form id="myForm" action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="video" type="file" name="video">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
    <img id="loading_gif" style="display:none" src="mysite/img/loading.gif">
</form>
```

I don't think $.ajax is the problem, because I removed it and still didn't work.

I already tried to separate toggle() from the rest of the submit by doing this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $("#loading_gif").toggle();
    $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

But it changed nothing.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want `async:false` remove this and your problem should go away.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It fixed my problem. I guess I was wrong.